# React - Redux, this.props.newCampaignInformation gives out undefined, I've tried console logging it in onStartChange function

Tags: reactjs, redux

React - Redux, this.props.newCampaignInformation gives out undefined, I've tried console logging it in onStartChange function. I should be able to get the data from the store right, could you please clarify this to me, help would be appreciated.

I have omitted a few methods to reduce the code. Thank you

```
     @connect((store) => {
        return {
            newCampaignInformation: store.DealReducer.newCampaignInformation
        };})





        const CalendarPicker = React.createClass({
    /**
         * Function called to get the initial state of the class
         *
         * @param void:
         * @return {{startValue: null, endValue: null, startOpen: boolean, endOpen: boolean}} the initial state of the class
         */
        getInitialState() {
            return {
                startValue: null,
                endValue: null,
                startOpen: false,
                endOpen: false,
            };
        },


        //MARK: Calendar Helper Functions


        /**
         * Function called when the start calendar changes being open
         *
         * @param startOpen: a boolean representing whether or not the start textfields calendar is open
         * @returns: void
         */


onStartChange(value) {
            console.log("new Camp Info")
            console.log(this.props.newCampaignInformation);
            console.log(value);
            this.setState({
                    startValue: value[0],
                    startOpen: false,
                    endOpen: false,

                });
                this.props.onChange(value, this.props.number);
            this.props.onOpenChange(this.props.newCampaignInformation);

        },


        /**
         * Function called when the selected end date changes
         *
         * @param value: an array with 2 values, the selected start date and end date
         * @returns: void
         */
        onEndChange(value) {

            console.log("new Camp Info")
            console.log(this.props.newCampInfo);
            console.log(value);
            this.setState({
                endValue: value[1],
            });

            this.props.onChange(value, this.props.number);//
            this.props.onOpenChange(this.props.newCampaignInformation);

        },

        handleStartTimeChange(num, val) {
            console.log(num);
            console.log(val);
            this.state.childElems[num].startTime = val/3600.0;
            this.update(num);
        },

        handleEndTimeChange(num, val) {
            console.log(num);
            console.log(val);
            this.state.childElems[num].endTime = val/3600.0;
            this.update(num);
        },

        // removeChild(num){
        //     this.props.removeChild(this.props.number);
        //     //this.update(num);
        // },


        //MARK: Render Function



        /**
         * Render function for this class
         *
         * @param void:
         * @returns: void
         */
        render() {
            const state = this.state;
            return (
                <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                    <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                        {/* <input type = "button" style={{ display: "flex"}} type="button" className="button-add" onClick ={() => {this.removeChild()}}/> */}
                        <div>
                            { this.props.startDateLabel &&
                                <label>{this.props.startDateLabel}</label>
                            }                       
                            <div>
                                <Picker
                                    ref="startDate"
                                    onOpenChange={this.onStartOpenChange}
                                    type="start"
                                    showValue={state.startValue}
                                    open={this.state.startOpen}
                                    disabledDate={this.disabledBeforeStartDate}
                                    value={[state.startValue, state.endValue]}
                                    onChange={this.onStartChange}
                                    inputBorderColor={this.props.startDateBorderColor}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <div>
                            { this.props.startTimeLabel &&
                                <label>{this.props.startTimeLabel}</label>
                            }
                            <TimePicker
                                className="timePickerSelect"
                                value={this.props.startTimeValue}
                                onChange={this.props.handleStartTimeChange.bind(this)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{display: "flex",  marginLeft: "5%"}}>
                    <div style={{display: "flex"}}>
                        <div>
                            { this.props.endDateLabel &&
                                <label>{this.props.endDateLabel}</label>
                            }
                            <div>
                                <Picker
                                    onOpenChange={this.onEndOpenChange}
                                    open={this.state.endOpen}
                                    type="end"
                                    showValue={state.endValue}
                                    disabledDate={this.disabledStartDate}
                                    value={[state.startValue, state.endValue]}
                                    onChange={this.onEndChange}
                                    inputBorderColor={this.props.endDateBorderColor}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <div>
                            { this.props.endTimeLabel &&
                                <label>{this.props.endTimeLabel}</label>
                            }
                            <TimePicker
                                className="timePickerSelect"
                                value={this.props.endTimeValue}
                                onChange={this.props.handleEndTimeChange.bind(this)}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            );
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The decorator syntax you are using is only going to work on ES6 class components. It will not work when using React.createClass. So something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ 
  newCampaignInformation: state.DealReducer.newCampaignInformation 
}))

@connect(mapStateToProps)
class CalendarPicker extends React.Components {
  ...
}
```

You can use connect without a decorator like so using ES6 class components, functional stateless components, or React.createClass components

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ 
  newCampaignInformation: state.DealReducer.newCampaignInformation 
}))

connect(mapStateToProps)(CalendarPicker)
```